# Can we use RubyOnRails for Banking and financial transactions domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, frameworks, dsl, financial

Can we use RubyOnRails framework to develop websites for financial transactions & banking transcations.

Is RubyonRails a DSL for banking Domains.

Some days on DSL, i believe most of the facts of Banking system are static and they may not need any subsequent alterations.. simultaneously.
So defining a DSL, one way process must work.

Comment: I have been in the world of rubyonrails for nearly 50 months, and i have always seen developers working in non secure domains, well if it has a good fit for banking & financial transction web domins. surely we can recommend rubyonrails.

Comment: Surely, my point was not about ahich bank, I have been working in ROR domain for nearly 36 months, so never heard from RubyonRails website in banking.

Comment: I really dislike this question, it is incredibly argumentative and vague, there is no real way to answer it.

Comment: A DSL is by definition a Domain-Specific Language. As Ruby is not specifically designed for the banking and financial industries, it is not a DSL for those. But as Michael Gee says below, it makes it easy to define your own DSLs on top of the core language.

Answer (score 4):

Banking transactions are all done in stored procedures in software and databases independent of the web interface to your bank account, so you could use any web framework, but this is one of the only areas where you have sufficiently complex transactional rules that an enterprise Java stack actually makes sense.  RAILS was once optimized for simple CRUD but has become much more mature in the last decade. I would suggest looking into [JRuby](https://www.jruby.org/), which is Ruby on top of the Java Virtual Machine, because you will have a much nicer time operating RAILS on the JVM in a high secure, high reliability environment like a financial institution.

Comment: I agree banking transactions are done completely on stored procedures on Database side, my point on this question was the secutirities available on the domain specific for banking.

practically mostly i suppose .Net & J2EE is used for this purpose.
never heard od website in ROR for banking.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can.  Ruby on Rails can perform the same tasks as any other web framework.  Maybe you should pose a question about a particular task that you think would be hard for Ruby on Rails, and we can address that.

Ruby on Rails is not a DSL for banking.  Ruby makes it easy to define your own DSLs, and Ruby on Rails is a good way to get that business logic available over the internet.